# chang parameter.ini to parameter.yml

Tags: symfony, config, file-format

I changed the `parameter.ini` file to `parameter.yml`. But  white page displaying in the browser.

My code: parameter.yml

```
 parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host=localhost
    database_port=22
    database_name=traxerp_cons
    database_user=root
    database_password=console
    mailer_transport=smtp
    mailer_host=localhost
    mailer_user=null
    mailer_password=null
    locale=en
    secret="b538e3680321a85b2e39a3d1772e0b711ff9371c"
```

config.yml

imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }

Answer (score 0):

Change all occurrences of `=` to `:`.

Also check the logs to see why the application is failing.

Comment: Error is:FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/var/www/html/traxerpconstruction/app/config/parameters.yml" from "/var/www/html/traxerpconstruction/app/config/config.yml".

Comment: Like I said, check the logs to find out the exact reason your app fails.

Comment: After changing the error:parse_ini_file(/var/www/html/traxerpconstruction/app/config/parameters.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/traxerpconstruction/vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Configurator/Configurator.php line 179

Comment: After changing the file name parameters . ini to parameters . yml  in Configurator.php mentioned in above path , the error displayed in the browser is :       InvalidArgumentException: The /var/www/html/traxerpconstruction/app/config/parameters.yml file is not valid.

Comment: Try disabling `SensionDistrubitonBundle` in `AppKernel`. It's hardwired to look for `parameters.ini` in Symfony 2.0.